# WebSocket binary stream faster than HTTP2 download, why?

Tags: websocket, http2

I'm trying to understand why downloading many small (200kb) binary files over a single WebSocket connection appears to be twice as fast as downloading the same data directly from the browser (Chrome) leveraging HTTP2.

The number of files vary from 100 to 3000 and it seems to consistently be faster over WebSocket.

The WebSocket implementation runs on Node.js (`ws` package) and downloads up to 50 files at the same time and sends each of them as binary message to the browser.

The HTTP2 implementation is downloading up to 50 files (but I tested with different limits too) using `fetch`.

I'm preconnecting to the origin (since it's different from the one where I'm running the web app), and both the implementations use the same exact URLs to download the data.

There doesn't seem to be any overhead during the HTTP requests so I don't really understand why the WebSocket is still faster.

I'm looking for general suggestions on how to debug the matter, or some canonical answers that explain at a theoretical level why this is happening.

[image]

Comment: I know you said you're using Node's ws, but are you able to share the code where you are setting up the requests? You can obfuscate/change any private information.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I'm unable to share the code as it's a lot and non public, but the general idea is we have several promises calling `https.request`, reading the response as it is received, push the chunks in a buffer and once the request is complete the promise is resolved. These promises run on a fn that limits concurrency to 50